# Play Framework - Get scheduled task status

Tags: java, playframework, task, scheduler

I'm working with Java Play Framework (2.3.6) and have some problems handeling scheduled tasks. Sometimes some of my recurring tasks crash with an exception. So I want to create a website to check the status of my scheduling tasks to have a quick view, if each tasks still runs without problems.
I know, I have also to check the exceptions but the website would be a nice controlling tool.

So I have some scheduled tasks like this one:

```
ExecutionContext dispatcher = Akka.system().dispatcher();

FiniteDuration timeNow = Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
FiniteDuration time1m = Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

Recorder recorderTask = new Recorder(); // implements Runnable
Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(timeNow, time1m, recorderTask, dispatcher);
```

Now, is there any possibility to check the status of my task (like it's alive)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not just catch the exception to prevent the task from crashing, and log the error?

Comment: First, I want an overview for many tasks. And I'm using Apache Commons and sometimes it just crash without any exception.

Comment: All you really get from scheduling a task is a `Cancellable`, which will *only* tell you if the task has been cancelled or not (crashed does not count as cancelled). I don't see how it "just crashes" without an exception--it can probably be prevented. The scheduler just isn't as sophisticated as you want it to be.